# Assigning array of char to a passed reference to a function

Tags: c, argument-passing

I am trying to create a program that will return the value read from a text2.text file but it seems like it doesn't return anything on the *buffer pointer. When I try to check the string inside "buffer" in the checkValue function it displays the data inside the text2.text but when it goes back to function main it doesn't shows up. Any suggestions how I could pass the value to main function? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct VALUE_READER
{
    char *result;
    char *fileName;
    char *sectionName;
    char *keyName;

} Value_reader;

void checkValue(FILE *name_of_file, char *buffer, int size_of_file) 
{
    int i;
    char holder[size_of_file];
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size_of_file);


    printf("%d \n",size_of_file);

    for (i = 0; i < size_of_file; i++) {
        holder[i] = fgetc(name_of_file);
        if (holder[i] == EOF) 
            break;
    }
    holder[i] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size_of_file; i++)
        *(buffer+i) = holder[i];

}

int main()
{
    Value_reader *vr1;
    FILE *testFile;
    int size_of_file;

    testFile = fopen("test2.txt", "r");

    fseek(testFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_of_file = ftell(testFile);
    fseek(testFile, 0, SEEK_SET); 


    if (NULL == testFile) {
        printf("File not found!\n");
    }

    else {
        vr1->result = malloc(sizeof(char) * 400);

        checkValue(testFile, vr1->result, size_of_file);
        printf("\nThe data inside are:\n\"%s\"\n", vr1->result);

        free(vr1->result);
        fclose(testFile);
    }

}
```

Comment: In function `checkValue`, remove the line `buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size_of_file);`. And in function `main`, change the constant `400` to `size_of_file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocate a buffer in your `main` with a call to `malloc`. You then pass that pointer to `checkValue`. Inside `checkValue` you ignore the pointer that was passed in and allocate a new buffer. You write to that new buffer, but then there is no way for the caller to see what you wrote because you wrote to a buffer private to `checkValue`.

Either:

1. Write to the buffer supplied by the caller, or
2. Allocate the buffer in `checkValue` and return that buffer to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You're allocing a char*:

```
vr1->result = malloc(sizeof(char) * 400);
```

Then passing this to checkValue. However inside checkValue, you're overwriting this pointer with your own newly malloc'd memory:

```
buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size_of_file);
```

So any memory writing you do after that point is to *that* buffer which is local to your function. Your options are:

1. Use the buffer provided to the function rather than malloc again inside the function
2. Pass the char** instead of the char*, then you can populate a pointer in the caller with memory which is alloc'd inside the function. e.g.:

   checkValue(testFile, &vr1->result, size_of_file);

then in your function something like:

```
void checkValue(FILE *name_of_file, char **buffer, int size_of_file) 
{
    ...
    *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size_of_file);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created an object of "Value_reader" for "vr1" to refer to.

And this statement "vr1->result = " in main() is undefined. You're trying to de-reference an un-initialized pointer.
Allocate a struct object for "vr1" pointer to point to. Change the line in main to:

```
vr1 = malloc(sizeof(Value_reader));
```